# Cloud Storage Transfer Service fails with BigQuery partitioned table

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I have create a partitioned table partitioned by day, then set up a BigQuery Transfers process that brings CSV files from a Google Cloud Storage Bucket.

```
PARTITION BY _PARTITIONDATE
OPTIONS(
  expiration_timestamp=TIMESTAMP  "2035-01-01 00:00:00 UTC" ,
  partition_expiration_days=1
  )
```

With non partitioned table in BigQuery, it works however with this partition table it throws the error:

> "Failed to start job for table XXXXX with error INVALID_ARGUMENT:
> Incompatible table partitioning specification. Expects partitioning specification interval(type:day),
> but input partitioning specification is ; JobID: YYYYY"

Can anyone help here please.

Comment: Can you detail more your configuration of the transfer?

Comment: Maybe, it's because your table is partitioned by day.  But your data is not according to the partitioning specification (type:day).  https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-partitioned-table-data